# cupy.cuda.memory.OutOfMemoryError: Out of memory allocating 80,384 bytes (allocated so far: 0 bytes)

Tags: cupy

When I tried to perform a matrix multiplication using a 10000x10000 matrix placed on GPU 1 with CuPy, I received an OutOfMemoryError. So I tried performing the same operation using a 100x100 matrix placed on GPU 1, but I encountered the same error.: cupy.cuda.memory.OutOfMemoryError: Out of memory allocating 80,384 bytes (allocated so far: 0 bytes).

here is my code：

```
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np
matrix_A2 = np.random.rand(100, 100)
matrix_B2 = np.random.rand(100, 100)
with cp.cuda.Device(1):
     csr_matrix_A2_gpu1 = cp.asarray(matrix_A2)
     csr_matrix_B2_gpu1 = cp.asarray(matrix_B2)
memrory=cp.get_default_memory_pool().used_bytes()
print('memrory:',memrory)
C11=cp.matmul(csr_matrix_A2_gpu1,csr_matrix_B2_gpu1)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dzyao/zsf/Matrix/scipy_matrix.py", line 54, in <module>
    C11=cp.matmul(csr_matrix_A2_gpu1,csr_matrix_B2_gpu1)
  File "/home/dzyao/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cupy/_core/_gufuncs.py", line 669, in __call__
    outs = cupy.empty(out_shape, dtype=ret_dtype, order=filter_order)
  File "/home/dzyao/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cupy/_creation/basic.py", line 22, in empty
    return cupy.ndarray(shape, dtype, order=order)
  File "cupy/_core/core.pyx", line 136, in cupy._core.core.ndarray.__new__
  File "cupy/_core/core.pyx", line 224, in cupy._core.core._ndarray_base._init
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 742, in cupy.cuda.memory.alloc
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 1419, in cupy.cuda.memory.MemoryPool.malloc
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 1440, in cupy.cuda.memory.MemoryPool.malloc
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 1120, in cupy.cuda.memory.SingleDeviceMemoryPool.malloc
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 1141, in cupy.cuda.memory.SingleDeviceMemoryPool._malloc
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 1379, in cupy.cuda.memory.SingleDeviceMemoryPool._try_malloc
cupy.cuda.memory.OutOfMemoryError: Out of memory allocating 80,384 bytes (allocated so far: 0 bytes).
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qglSg.png)